# Trying to deploy Laravel 4 website on godaddy shared hosting results into exception

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am trying to deploy my laravel4 website in shared hosting where. 
I have a website `http://healthscapeseries.com` so now when I write `http://healthscapeseries.com/myappname/public/` I want my app to open . I uploaded `myappname` inside the folder that corresponds to my websites index page .

I am getting following error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

11. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php148
10. Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection match
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php1054
9. Illuminate\Routing\Router findRoute
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php1022
8. Illuminate\Routing\Router dispatchToRoute
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php1001
7. Illuminate\Routing\Router dispatch
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php775
6. Illuminate\Foundation\Application dispatch
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php745
5. Illuminate\Foundation\Application handle
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware.php72
4. Illuminate\Session\Middleware handle
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Queue.php47
3. Illuminate\Cookie\Queue handle
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Guard.php51
2. Illuminate\Cookie\Guard handle
…\vendor\stack\builder\src\Stack\StackedHttpKernel.php23
1. Stack\StackedHttpKernel handle
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php641
0. Illuminate\Foundation\Application run
…\public\index.php97
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you found any solution yet? If not then this might be one of the solution. What needs to be done is as follqws:

1. Copy all the files and folders including the public folder of your app to the "public html" folder of the shared hosting.
2. Copy all the contents of the laravel public folder to the "public html" folder.
3. Now just remove the Laravel's public folder.
4. Now Open up laravel's bootstrap/paths.php file and then change the change the path

   'public' => **DIR**.'/../public',

to

```
'public' => __DIR__.'/..',
```

5. Now open up the index.php file which was actually in your laravel's public folder but now in the "public html" folder and change

   require **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

   $app = require_once **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/start.php';

to

```
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/start.php';
```

Now you are good to go. Let me know the update. Good luck.